# How to preserve radio button value inside grid?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a grid with one row having a radio button list .

Based on this radio button list, a date is generated in another column.

If i allocate radio button for first time it works good and a date is created and so on...

but while I check another one from a different row after a week or two, the wrong thing happens.

I get a new date in all rows and it replaces the date created by the radio button two weeks back. :(

Comment: I think we are probably going to need to see some code to help you out with this one.

Comment: this question makes no sense. please provide details.

Comment: Probably a copy/paste error :) but should be easier with code...